# Why does string slicing with negative step print an empty string?

Tags: python, string

I have the following program:

```
str = 'abcd'
l = len(str)

str2 = str[l-1:0:-1] 

print(str2)

str2 = str[l-1:-1:-1] 

print(str2)
```

Why does the first `print()` output `dcb` and the second `print()` output an empty string ? Why doesn't the second `print()` output `dcba` ?

Comment: The numbers you use to split, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/13781503)

Comment: We expect you to use available documentation and resources before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

In the statement `str[l-1:0:-1]` - Last character upto 0th character not including the zeroth element. That's why you get `dcb`

In the statement `str2 = str[l-1:-1:-1]` you are going from 3rd index to 3rd index so empty string.

If you need all elements `str2 = str[l-1::-1]` would give `dcba`

Answer (score 0):

First case, `l=4`. You slice `abcd` from `3` to `0`, resulting in `dcb`. Second case you slice from `3` to `-1`. `-1` is the last element of the list/string. So you are sliciing from `3` to `3`, resulting in nothing.